# ¿Sería posible redireccionar el default de un bloque switch a alguno de los case previos?

Tags: java, android

Estoy probando un código con unos cuantos `case`, y para no tener que cambiar los valores que evalúa el bloque `switch` quisiera redirigir el `default` a los distintos `case` :) de ese modo no me veo obligado a cambiar el contenido cada vez, sino que voy redirigiendo y así pruebo cómo funcionaría en cada `case`.

Me explico:

```
public static void setBarColor(AppCompatActivity a, int colorTiempo) {
    ActionBar ab = a.getSupportActionBar();

    switch (colorTiempo) {
        case 1:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_adviento)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_adviento));
            break;
        case 2:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_cuaresma));
            break;
        case 3:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_blanco));
            break;
        case 5:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_blanco));
            break;
        case 61:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_blanco));
            break;
        case 7:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_ordinario)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_ordinario));
            break;

        case 8:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco)));
            a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_bar_blanco));
            break;

        default:
            /*Aquí, ir enviando a cada case: 1, 2, 3 ... así pruebo cada con un solo valor*/
            /*Redireccionar al case 1, por ejemplo, ¿será posible?*/
            break;
    }

}
```

O sea, actualmente los datos de mi código tienen el color `6`, pero yo lo altero temporalmente poniéndole `61` para forzarlo en el `default` y desde ahí ir redirigiendo a cada `case` para probar cómo se ven los colores en cada `case` sin tener que cambiar el valor del color en el origen de los datos.

¿Es posible esto?

Comment: Dejame ver si entendí, en el caso que en tu switch llega a la validacion por default, quieres volver a llamar al mismo switch pero asignandoler un valor nuevo, como dices asigarle el 1?, si ese es el caso seria implementar un método recursivo

Comment: Lo que quieres es llamar el metodo setBarColor una sola vez y que evalue todos los cases con sus respectivos valores?

Comment: @MiguelOsorio la cuestión es hacer que entre en el `default` y desde ahí indicarle que ejecute la acción de alguno de los `case`.  Es solamente para facilidad de probar cómo se verían los colores en cada case sin tener que estar copiando/pegando cada color en el `default` ni cambiando el valor del color en el origen de los datos. Simplemente hago que no se cumpla ninguna de las condiciones y en el `default`, en cada prueba, lo voy enviando a los `case`. O sea: 1ª prueba: lo mando al `case 1`, ejecuto el código y veo cómo se ven los colores; 2ª prueba: lo mando a `case 2` y ejecuto el código...

Comment: y si seteas el `colorTiempo` antes del case?

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¡claro! ¡Te puedes creer, ni se me ocurrió! ¡Claro, setear `colorTiempo` de forma manual dentro del método, claro...!

Comment: =P "debug by hardcoding" que le dicen

Comment: Y ¿no quieres hacer un random de colores, para el estatus bar?, o ¿deberán de ser estáticos dependiendo de alguna situación?

Comment: @MiguelOsorio deben ser estáticos según el valor de `colorTiempo`. Mi pregunta era para probar todas las posibilidades, ya que son varias, modificando lo menos posible los valores.

Comment: @aloMalbarez sugiero que pongas tu comentario como respuesta, pues sería la forma más simple de hacerlo: cambiar el valor de `colorTiempo` de forma manual dentro del método para fines de prueba.

Comment: Pero no creo que logres percibir cambios visualmente. A menos que interrumpas la ejecucion con un hilo dormido por cada cambio. Ya que el codigo debe ser asincrono en alguna parte si quieres notar el cambio visualmente. Si es que corres el metodo una sola vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de ver lo que propone alo, solo deseas probar uno por uno, Me refiero ver como se ve con cada color?

Comment: @Elenasys sí sí, es para prueba, sin tener que hacer demasiadas modificaciones de los datos. Lo más simple sería poner `colorTiempo` de forma manual e ir cambiando su valor. ¡No había caído en la cuenta!

Comment: Como comento @aloMalbarez es setear `colorTiempo` tal vez con valores random que oscilen desde el 1 al 8 de tus cases, para que solo tengas que refrescar tu activity sin tener que volver a hacer la compilacion

Comment: @MiguelOsorio no me importaría cambiar los valores de `colorTiempo` cada vez y refrescar la `Activity`, lo que quiero evitarme es el copy/paste de los distintos valores en el `default` para probar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Agregué una actualización en realidad en lugar de modificar el método, lo envio llamar cada n segundos para que se puedan visualizar los posibles cambios que realizará el método en la UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En este caso tendrías que llamar el mismo método, pero con diferentes parametros:

```
public static void setBarColor(AppCompatActivity a, int colorTiempo) {
    ActionBar ab = a.getSupportActionBar();

    switch (colorTiempo) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        default:
            /*Redireccionar al case 1, por ejemplo, ¿será posible?*/

            setBarColor(a, 1);  
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Actualización:

Para probar como se vería tu aplicación con diferentes colores, recursos, imagenes, etc, en mi caso para mostrar este tipo de cambios a un cliente o al product owner, lo realizo mediante un `Thread` de esta forma, importante el uso de `runOnUiThread()` ya que se realizarían operaciones en el UI Thread:

```
  //Declara variable contador.
  private int mycounter = 0;
```

Al iniciar la aplicación puedes agregar en el método `onCreate()` la llamada al método cada n segundos, en este caso cada segundo (1000 ms) :

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            //*Llamada a método.
                            Utils.setBarColor(mycounter, MainActivity.this);

                            mycounter++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

de esta forma no tienes que modificar tu método y obtendrías como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para mi esta es la mejor respuesta. Es misma que yo iba a dar.

Answer (score 2):

No tengo mucha experiencia con Java, pero si subís el default arriba, volverías a evaluar todos los casos. Es esto lo que necesitas?

```
switch (colorTiempo) 
{
  default: 
  //no poner break        
  case 1:
  break;
}
```

Comment: Por respetar la convención de que el `default` va al final, yo cambiaría el orden (primero `case 1` y luego `default`). Pero es una buena opción.

Answer (score 1):

Eso no se puede hacer. El funcionamiento del `switch` indica que cuando se encuentre un `case` que coincida con el valor de la variable pasada a este, se ejecutará el código existente desde dicho `case` hasta que se encuentre un `break` o hasta que se termine el código asociado al `switch`.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos el siguiente código:

```
int unNumero = 2;

switch (unNumero) {
    case 1 : System.out.println("Valor 1");
    case 2 : System.out.println("Valor 2");
    case 3 : System.out.println("Valor 3");
    default : System.out.println("Valor por defecto");
}
```

se imrpimirá

```
Valor 2
Valor 3
Valor por defecto
```

Ya que no se encuentra un `break` y se sigue ejecutando todo el código a partir del `case` que coincidió, aunque dicho código se encuentre dentro de otro `case`. Por eso que sea casi obligatorio el uso de los `break`, ya que de otro modo podemos tener un comportamiento no deseado.

Así es como funciona el `switch` en java, y no hay manera de redireccionar el flujo del programa (`goto` ya no está en uso) hacia otra `case. Sería un poco violar el paradigma de programación estructurada.

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar métodos dentro de los `case` y en el `default` llamar a los métodos de los `case` que quieras.

```
int unNumero = 2;

switch (unNumero) {
    case 1 : metodo1(); break;
    case 2 : metodo2(); break;
    case 3 : metodo3(); break;
    default : {
        metodo2();
        metodo3();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para forzar un case con (re)definir el valor de la variable `colorTiempo` antes del `switch` bastaría.

[E. Betanzos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73584/e-betanzos) da un mejor ejemplo del cómo funciona el asunto.

Comment: Qué me faltó por explicar sobre el funcionamiento del `switch`? Por otra parte, modificar el valor de la variable antes de entrar a `swicth` no modifica su funcionamiento, y menos permite redireccionar el flujo del programa de un `case` a otro, o del `default` hacia un `case` anterior.

Comment: No faltó nada en cuanto a como funciona el switch case, por eso te menciono en la respuesta. Lo que faltaría es el contexto que surgió en los comentarios acerca de qué es lo que se pretende lograr, en este caso era probar cada case, dentro de la función independientemente de los datos recibidos por la función.

Comment: Es cierto, pero entre que se publicó la pregunta (con un nombre que no tiene nada que ver con los comentarios) que me puse a redactar mi respuesta, no vi los comentarios explicando mejor lo que se intentaba lograr. Yo solo me limité a responder el porqué no se puede redirigir el flujo de un `case` a otro, que fue lo que se preguntó originalmente.

Comment: Te sugiero editar tu respuesta e incluir lo que expresa en el último párrafo de la pregunta, está reforzado en los comentarios: "probar cada case, dentro de la función independientemente de los datos recibidos por la función"

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es probar una lista de valores puedes utilizar una función recursiva. Así solo tendrías que definir dos listas del mismo tamaño asignando los colores correspondientes y para probar mas mezclas, solo tendrias que cambiar los valores de las listas en vez de crear `cases`.

```
private int[] toolbarColors = new int[]{
       R.color.color_toolbar_adviento,
       R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma,
       R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma,
       R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco,
       R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco,
       R.color.color_toolbar_ordinario,
       R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco
};

private int[] statusBarColors = new int[]{
        R.color.color_bar_adviento,
        R.color.color_bar_cuaresma,
        R.color.color_bar_blanco,
        R.color.color_bar_blanco,
        R.color.color_bar_blanco,
        R.color.color_bar_ordinario,
        R.color.color_bar_blanco
};

public void setBarColor(AppCompatActivity a, int colorTiempo) {

     if(colorTiempo >= toolbarColors.length || colorTiempo < 0)
        return;

     ActionBar ab = a.getSupportActionBar();
     ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(toolbarColors[colorTiempo])));
     a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(statusBarColors[colorTiempo]));
     setBarColor(a, colorTiempo++); // Llamada recursiva

}
```

y llamarias `setBarColor(a, 0); // 0 o donde quieres que inicie tu lista`

Como te comente, si quieres notar los cambios visualmente, debes definir un hilo dormido antes de llamar a la funcion recursiva. Ya que en tiempo lineal, solo se mostrara el ultimo elemento visualmente. Si quieres un metodo estatico, por igual las listas deben ser estaticas.